# What Mitsubishi van is this?

Tags: car, mitsubishi, 4wd, vehicle-identification

This is a Mitsubishi van; it says it's a 4x4.

Does anybody know model or year?

[image: van]

Answer (score 6):

Pretty sure it's this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitsubishi_Delica
I guess it's the third generation of the Mitsubishi Delica, pre-facelift.

Rougly from 1986 to 1994.

Also the country where it's from narrows down the options, as they look a tad different from each other depending on the country.

Comment: License plate suggests Europe, background hints to Greece. I would say it is what was called "L300 II Luxus Bus" in Germany because of that part between the headlights. The interior would give a lot of information. I think if it is not a diesel, the 4x4 version was only available as diesel after 1994. Very annoying to change the alternators belt as you had to work on one all copper screw...

Answer (score 4):

My best guess would be an early 90's (1991 ??) Mitsubishi Delica.

Answer (score 4):

It's a 3rd generation Mitsubishi Delica (L300), hard to tell exact year from that pic but I'd say pre-facelift (so pre-98) and the twin headlights suggest it possibly being the US version, which would have been badged as a "Wagon" since that appears to be the passenger version, the cargo version was badged (imaginatively) as the "Van" and that would place it 1987-91 (ish)

Comment: I doubt it's a US version, considering I found the near duplicate of this van [in this image](https://goo.gl/images/RNtVDJ) which actually shows a license plate. The image is used all over a bunch of different Hungarian websites (as long as .hu is Hungary, lol). It is badged as an L300 (I believe ... pixelation sux in the image) on the side. I just highly doubt the one in the OP's image is from the US. Also, look at the red sign in the background.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Pretty sure the picture is taken in Greece. Also the license plate on the left is blue, white background and black letters. Almost certain it is, tho :)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 yep.. on looking closer there's no way that's taken in the US! I was going off the fact that it was LHD and had twin headlights and hadn't really looked at the non-van bits of the image!

Comment: Greece, athens, indeed! you guys are amazing! :) PS thanks to everybody